# What is postgres firing order for multiple row-level triggers on the same event?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have searched but cannot find a clear answer to this question. Suppose I have two AFTER triggers on on INSERT on the same table: trigA and trigB with corresponding trigger functions funcA and funcB. When I insert multiple rows, is the firing sequence this one:

```
FOR EACH row DO funcA END; FOR EACH row DO funcB END;
```

Or is it this one:

```
FOR EACH row DO funcA, DO funcB END;
```

I need to know whether (a) funcA processes ALL rows before funcB is fired, or whether (b) both functions are invoked on a row-by-row basis. My logic requires that the funcA actions on ALL rows become visible (complete) BEFORE funcB is fired.

I cannot find any clear guidance on this firing sequence question. Thanks for the support.

As explained above, not sure what is supposed to happen vs. what actually happens.

Comment: If you are doing a row trigger then each function is called per row in alphabetical order by name. If you want to see all the rows then use a statement trigger possibly in conjunction with a `transition relation` as explained here [Create Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html). **Note** you cannot modify rows with an after trigger so I am not sure what *... funcA actions on ALL rows* means?

Comment: That should have been,  *each trigger is called per row in alphabetical order by name*.

Comment: Adrian, I am modifying rows in another table using bulk insert input so the "Note" does not apply, and I understand the alphabetical sequencing. But please confirm that (as per your response), the execution sequence is "FOR EACH row DO all triggers (in alpha order)", and it is not "FOR EACH trigger (in alpha order) DO all rows END". This will really help. Thanks

Comment: @Eelke There are 4 types of triggers that can be defined for a table DML statement. 1. `Before Statement` , 2. `Before Row`, 3. `After Row`,and 4 `After Statement`. Statement level triggers fire once while row level triggers may fire multiple times for a single DML.  You may want to take a look at [Create Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createtrigger.html).

Comment: @Eelke thanks for feedback. Your "Create Trigger" manual reference still does not tell me the row/trigger looping sequence. Think of this problem as two nested row and trigger loops - which one of these is the outer loop: the trigger loop (i.e. FOR EACH trigger DO all rows END) or the row loop (FOR EACH row DO all triggers END)?

Comment: If you are using  `FOR EACH ROW` triggers will fire the triggers in alphabetical order for each row. If you want the triggers to fire in alphabetical order after a given statement has operated on all its rows then use `FOR EACH STATEMENT`. The docs here [Create Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) are quite straight forward on this: *If multiple triggers of the same kind are defined for the same event, they will be fired in alphabetical order by name.*. If you don't believe it set up a simple test case to verify.

Comment: @All thanks for the great feedback - the trigger_test proves that the execution order is: "FOR EACH row DO all triggers END", meaning that all triggers are fired row-by-row  basis and triggerB does NOT wait until triggerA has processed all rows, before it is invoked. This is not the behaviour I was looking for, but simply changing triggerB to a statement trigger (instead of a row trigger) I get the behaviour I need: triggerB only fires AFTER triggerA has processed all the rows.

Comment: The lesson is that firing sequence depends not only on trigger naming, but also on the combination of statement and row triggers linked to the same event. I suspect some combinations may produce unpredicatable behaviours. We can close this query but not sure how to do that since I am fairly new to this platform.

Comment: I forgot to add the BEFORE and AFTER settings will also affect the firing sequence - I think a firing table showing the sequencing effects of all combinations would be useful.

Comment: @Eelke, that is nonsense, the page tells you exactly what is going on; *If multiple triggers of the same kind are defined for the same event, they will be fired in alphabetical order by name.* and at bottom of page *SQL specifies that multiple triggers should be fired in time-of-creation order. PostgreSQL uses name order, which was judged to be more convenient.*. There are special considerations for `ON CONFLICT` inserts and they are spelled out on the  `CREATE TRIGGER` page and [Trigger Overview](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html). Bottom line order is defined.

Comment: Firing table? You mean like the table here [Create Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) that starts below the line *The following table summarizes which types of triggers may be used on tables, views, and foreign tables:*.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the point i am trying to make is that working out the trigger firing sequence is not intuitive as your useful trigger_test below has shown, and this is NOT clarified anywhere in the manual. Intuitively, I would expect "FOR EACH trigger DO all rows END" (with triggers in the outer loop), but your test has shown that the actual execution order is "FOR EACH row DO all triggers END" (with rows in the outer loop). Show me where this is clearly explained in the manual.

Comment: Further, when I changed trigger B into a statement level trigger, the execution sequence switches to "FOR EACH row DO triggerA END; FOR triggerB DO all rows". That is why I called for clear table showing the sequencing (and other) effects of these trigger configuration parameter combinations.

Comment: See **UPDATE** to answer.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver In response to your update: Create Trigger tables do not explain the trigger firing sequence for multiple triggers on same event - they only explain what parameter combinations are allowed. To use your trigger_test as an example, a table that explains the firing sequence for (e.g.,) these combinations would be useful:

combination1
triga | insert | after | row-level + trigB | insert | after | row-level

Comment: continued ...

combination1
triga | insert | after | row-level + trigB | insert | after | row-level

combination2
triga | insert | before | row-level + trigB | insert | after | row-level

combination3
triga | insert | after | row-level + trigB | insert | after | statement-level + trigB | insert | after | row-level.
and so on ....

Comment: I explained that in the **UPDATE** to my answer, *BEFORE ROW, BEFORE STATEMENT, AFTER ROW AND AFTER STATEMENT*. Within each of those actions multiple triggers on the same action will fire in alphabetical order. So combination 1) triga,trigb 2) triga,trigb 3) triga, trigb. You can't have duplicate trigger names for a given table so `... + trigB | insert | after | row-level. and so on ....` won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Simple test to show how it works:

```
create table trigger_test(id integer, fld_1 varchar, fld_2 boolean);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.trga()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'trga fnc id: %, fld_1: %', NEW.id, NEW.fld_1;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$
;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.trgb()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'trgb fnc id: %, fld_2: %', NEW.id, NEW.fld_2;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$
;

create trigger triggerA AFTER INSERT ON trigger_test FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION trgA();
create trigger triggerB AFTER INSERT ON trigger_test FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION trgB();

insert into trigger_test values (1, 'a', 't'), (2, 'b', 'f'), (3, 'c', 't');

NOTICE:  trga fnc id: 1, fld_1: a
NOTICE:  trgb fnc id: 1, fld_2: t
NOTICE:  trga fnc id: 2, fld_1: b
NOTICE:  trgb fnc id: 2, fld_2: f
NOTICE:  trga fnc id: 3, fld_1: c
NOTICE:  trgb fnc id: 3, fld_2: t
INSERT 0 3
```

**UPDATE**

Trigger sequencing.

From docs [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html):

> A trigger that is marked FOR EACH ROW is called once for every row that the operation modifies.

> In contrast, a trigger that is marked FOR EACH STATEMENT only executes once for any given operation, regardless of how many rows it modifies (in particular, an operation that modifies zero rows will still result in the execution of any applicable FOR EACH STATEMENT triggers).

> If multiple triggers of the same kind are defined for the same event, they will be fired in alphabetical order by name.

Given the three things above the sequencing is pretty straight forward. For a given kind of trigger ROW or STATEMENT on a given event INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE the triggers will fire in alphabetical order. So a multiple ROW triggers for one event, say UPDATE, will fire for each row processed alphabetically. Multiple STATEMENT triggers will fire alphabetically at the completion of the statement. If that statement covers multiple rows then each trigger will fire after the action on all the affected rows, then the next alphabetical trigger will fire. If you mix ROW and STATEMENT then the ROW triggers will fire as each row is processed(again in alphabetical order if more then one) then the STATEMENT triggers in alphabetical order. Further sequencing can be done with BEFORE and AFTER where those qualifiers add another level, so BEFORE ROW, BEFORE STATEMENT, AFTER ROW AND AFTER STATEMENT. Where for each combination the firing order is alphabetical by trigger name.

Comment: thanks for all the feedback - your update attempts to explain the firing sequence for mixed statement/row-level triggers but I still think a simple table illustrating the effects of different combinations would be more effective. When I find find time, I will compile such table myself (using your trigger_test snippet) and share it as my own small contribution to postgres knowledge. Thanks again.